# GeoServer CSS rotation with env and property name

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-css-module

Using GeoServer CSS extension

```
 mark-rotation:  [env('rot',2)];
```

ends in

```
    <sld:Rotation>
        <ogc:Function name="env">
            <ogc:Literal>rot</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:Function>
     </sld:Rotation>
```

How should my style look like to add a property name to rotation:

```
 <sld:Rotation>
    <ogc:Add>               
    <ogc:PropertyName>mystyle</ogc:PropertyName>
       <ogc:Function name="env">
          <ogc:Literal>rot</ogc:Literal>
          <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
       </ogc:Function>
    </ogc:Add>
  </sld:Rotation>
```

I have tried

```
 mark-rotation:  [env('rot',2),mystyle];
 mark-rotation:  [mystyle],[env('rot',2)];
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? Your SLD makes no sense (and will not parse)

Comment: I have not written the sld but try to translate it into css. (edited the sld as I forgot the closing add.) You say it makes no sense. Wouldn´t the SLD rotate the point by use of PropertyName or variable "rot" or default value 2?

Comment: How about mark-rotation:  [env('rot',2)+mystyle];

Comment: Yes ! that did it. If you post it as answer I can accept it. One more question. Do I read the filter correctly: "Wouldn´t the SLD rotate the point by use of PropertyName or variable "rot" or default value 2?" thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To produce a rotation of ( the rot variable or 2 ) plus the value of the property mystyle you should use:

```
mark-rotation: [env('rot',2)+mystyle];
```

To generate SLD that uses rot, followed by mystyle, or 2 you should use something like (and I haven't tested this). If it doesn't work you can check the [syntax page](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/css/filters.html):

```
mystyle is null {
  mark-rotation:  [env('rot',2)]
}
mystyle is not null {  
  mark-rotation: [mystyle];
}
```

Comment: Simply Great! I haven´t found the + operator. If it´s documented can you point me to ?

Comment: See http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/cql/index.html