# Using CSS var function in GeoServer CSS styling

Tags: geoserver, css, geoserver-css-module

I wanted to check if I could use something like the [CSS var() function](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp) with the GeoServer CSS plugin styles.
Something to look like:

```
    :root {
        --land-color: #f2efe9;
      }
    /* @title Land */
    [featurecla = 'Land'] {
        background-color: var(land-color);
      }
```

Except obviously for more than one variable.
I came across [GeoServer CSS Styling variable](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/323496) but could not get the only suggested solution there to work.

This is what I tried:

```
/* &env=land-color:#dd0000 */
/* @title Land */
[featurecla = 'Land'] {
fill: env('land-color');
stroke: #f2efe9;
}
```

The result I want to get is setting a color (or any other style variable, like halo-radius or font-size) once and the use it by name in entire stylesheet, making it easier to edit it across the document.

I keep getting a default white polygon with black stroke when using this. The CSS validates properly but does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

GeoServer CSS does not support the var function, or setting variables at the beginning of the stylesheet.

To add such support you could follow the guide at https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/Successfully-requesting-and-integrating-fixes,-improvements-and-new-features-in-GeoServer